# How to load face-api.js shard models in a hosted environment on AWS Amplify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-amplify

I am trying to use the **face-api.js** library to do some emotion detection on a live webcam feed. It works perfectly on a local environment but when I try to host it on AWS Amplify, it gives me an error such as

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Based on the provided shape, [1,1,16,32], the tensor should have 512 values but has 231
```

This is the code that tries to load the models:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if(checked){
            const MODEL_URL = './models';
            const initModels = async () => {
                await face.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
                await face.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
                await face.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
                await face.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
                enableWebcam();
            }
            initModels();
        }
    }, [checked]);
```

This is the models that are found in the ***./public*** folder:

[image]

I found that people had a similiar problem [here](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/issues/131) and I attempted the solution by trying to change all the shard files to a *.shard* or *.bin* file extension and changed the manifest.json accordingly but it still gives me the same error.

I've been trying to debug this all day but can't seem to find a solution. Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.
This is my first time working with ML models in a web application environment using React and AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after hours of trying to debug it, the solution was fairly simple. I just had to load the models in a different way like shown here:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (checked) {
            const MODEL_URL = `/models`
            const initModels = async () => {
                Promise.all([
                    face.loadTinyFaceDetectorModel(MODEL_URL),
                    face.loadFaceLandmarkModel(MODEL_URL),
                    face.loadFaceRecognitionModel(MODEL_URL),
                    face.loadFaceExpressionModel(MODEL_URL)
                ]).then(enableWebcam);
            }
            initModels();
        }
    }, [checked]);
```

Comment: what is shard1 & shard2  of same model?